# "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/tools/branches/Contracts/js/autosize.js"

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to add a js file in the html and it gives me the error

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/tools/branches/Contracts/js/autosize.js"
```

Not sure why. I added the file autosize.js in /webroot/js  and I reference to it in my html as

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('autosize'); ?>
```

am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your vhost of this application configured to APP/webroot and not APP/?